Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException
i have a problem When I deploy the project I sometimes get this error and I don't know what it is due to.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
).......
I don't know if I have something wrong in the application properties, which is the following
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://*******:3306/*******
jdbc.user=******
jdbc.password=******

connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

logging.level.org.springframework.security=INFO

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.mvc.media-types.js=application/javascript
spring.http.encoding.force-response-content-type=true
spring.http.encoding.content-type=application/javascript

spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.connection-timeout=10000

server.servlet.context-path=/

And these are the dependencies I currently have (could it be some dependency conflict?)
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7.Final</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.16</version>
    </dependency>-->
  </dependencies>

Finally, here I pass some configuration classes, I have the @Transactional annotation in all the service classes
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"es.proyecto.webpersonal"})
@PropertySource("classpath:project.properties")
public class App 
{
    @Autowired
    public Environment env;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource secutiryDataSoruce = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            secutiryDataSoruce.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        }catch(PropertyVetoException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        secutiryDataSoruce.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        secutiryDataSoruce.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        secutiryDataSoruce.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        secutiryDataSoruce.setInitialPoolSize(getStringToInt("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        secutiryDataSoruce.setMinPoolSize(getStringToInt("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        secutiryDataSoruce.setMaxPoolSize(getStringToInt("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        secutiryDataSoruce.setMaxIdleTime(getStringToInt("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));
        return secutiryDataSoruce;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment environment) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("es.proyecto.webpersonal.entities");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties(environment));
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    private Properties hibernateProperties(Environment environment) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    
    //Metodo para convertir un string a entero 
    //Revisar
    public int getStringToInt(String entero) {
        String propVal = env.getProperty(entero);
        int propPool = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        return propPool;
    }
    
}

And this is the servlet
package es.proyecto.webpersonal.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyServletSpringInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[]{App.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}

It should be said that I am simply using a Spring project, my version of Java is 1.8 and this error sometimes appears and sometimes not only when I deploy the database configurations (address, name and user) to the server. They are correct but I can't find why sometimes it does it to me.
This is an example of one of the service classes I have.
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import es.proyecto.webpersonal.dao.HabilidadesDao;
import es.proyecto.webpersonal.entities.Habilidades;
import es.proyecto.webpersonal.service.HabilidadesService;

@Service
@Transactional
public class HabilidadesServiceImpl implements HabilidadesService {
    
    private final HabilidadesDao habilidadesDao; 
    
    @Autowired
    public HabilidadesServiceImpl(HabilidadesDao habilidadesDao) {
        this.habilidadesDao = habilidadesDao;
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Habilidades> getHabilidades() {
        return habilidadesDao.getHabilidades();
    }

    @Override
    public Habilidades getHabilidad(int id) {
        return habilidadesDao.getHabilidad(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void addHabilidad(Habilidades habilidad) {
        habilidadesDao.addHabilidad(habilidad);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateHabilidad(int id, String nuevoNombre) {
        habilidadesDao.updateHabilidad(id, nuevoNombre);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteHabilidad(int id) {
        habilidadesDao.deleteHabilidad(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void enabledHabilidad(int id) {
        habilidadesDao.enabledHabilidad(id);
    }

}

I have tried changing the database and changing the version of the mysql connector, I have also changed some properties of the connection pool but I still get the error when deploying, Also, I have tried using two free database services, one is db4free and the other is freemysqlhosting and I get the same error in both.

For starters stop mixing jars from different versions of Spring and incompatible other Spring portfolio jars. You also have Spring Boot in there as a dependency but judging from what you have you aren't using it. At least for starters fix your dependencies to be compatible and for Spring from 1 version of the framework. Finally you are using the LocalSessionFactoryBean but configure the JpaTransactionManager use the HibernateTransactionManager instead.
